# Realm sync remote to local

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous, react-native, realm

I've just started using Realm for Reactnative. Looking through example codes and repositories I managed to make RealmObjectServer and persisted some data there.

Steps I took for making a local server:

1. Downloaded Realm Mobile Platform from the official [site](https://realm.io/docs/get-started/installation/mac/)
2. Run start-object-server.command
3. It asked me to create a user in `localhost:8090`, I did
4. Managed to login a user from app and add some data in the server, using something like this:

```js
Realm.Sync.User.login(
  'http://127.0.0.1:9080',
  'asd@asd.com', // username
  'asd', // password
  (err, user) => {
    if(err) {
      return console.log(err);
    }
    console.log(user);
    let realm = new Realm({
      schema: [this.PersonSchema],
      sync: {
        user,
        url: 'realm://localhost:9080/~/test'
      }
    })

    this.setState({ number: realm.objects('Person').length })

    realm.write(() => {
     realm.create('Person', { name: 'timon', age: 29 }, true)
    })
  }
)
```

*The above code snippet will not run, I was not able to format the code properly in this WYSWYG :D*

Now, I can get all the data related to PersonSchema from remote object server, but I am not able to get the same from local realm (client side). If I want to call the same schema (PersonSchema) from client mobile, I should do this? (not getting data by doing this)

```
let realm = new Realm({ schema: [this.PersonSchema] })
realm.objects('Person').map((item, i) => {
  return console.log(item);
}
```

Realm should sync the data itself! 
Is there a function I should call to sync data?
What would be the proper way to sync data between local and remote DB?
Are there any good examples or tutorials for realm? I could not find anything in official documents.

**Note:** If I create a new instance without using sync property or without using any user data or outside login function scope - it will make a local object and I can access it. But no sync-ing.

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View
} from 'react-native';
import Realm from 'realm'

export default class realmTest extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = { number: null }

    this.PersonSchema = {
      name: 'Person',
      properties: {
        name: 'string',
        age: 'int'
      }
    }

  }

  login(){
    Realm.Sync.User.login(
      'http://127.0.0.1:9080',
      'asd@asd.com',
      'asd',
      (err, user) => {
        if(err) {
          return console.log(err);
        }
        console.log(user);

        let realm = new Realm({
          schema: [this.PersonSchema],
          sync: {
            user,
            url: 'realm://localhost:9080/~/test'
          }
        })

        this.setState({ number: realm.objects('Person').length })

        // realm.write(() => {
        //   realm.create('Person', { name: 'timon', age: 29 }, true)
        // })

      }
    )
  }

  componentWillMount(){
    this.login()

  }

  render() {

    let realm = new Realm({ schema: [this.PersonSchema] })
    // realm.write(() => {
    //   realm.create('Person', { name: 'timon', age: 29 }, true)
    // })
    console.log(realm);
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.welcome}>
          Remote Objects (number): {this.state.number}
        </Text>
        <View>
          <Text>
            Local Objects (number): {realm.objects('Person').length}
          </Text>
        </View>
        {realm.objects('Person').map((item, i) => {
          return(
            <View key={i}>
              <Text>{item.name}</Text>
            </View>
          )
        })}

      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
  },
  welcome: {
    fontSize: 20,
    textAlign: 'center',
    margin: 10,
  },
  instructions: {
    textAlign: 'center',
    color: '#333333',
    marginBottom: 5,
  },
});

AppRegistry.registerComponent('realmTest', () => realmTest);
```

Comment: Hi Ank,

Is your code snippet running in React Native? If so, when you create the person in your script, it adds it to the local realm which is automatically synced with the server.

You say that the schema is created on the server just fine. Does this mean that you don't see the created object anywhere? Or did you see it, but only on the server? Because that should not be possible.

Comment: Hi, Yes it is running fine on ReactNative. I'll try to explain more clearly now. If I make a local realm it will be accessible through local realm only and same with remote. I am updating my question with full index.ios.js file so you can understand better - or if you want I can create a repo for the same. Thanks!

Comment: You shouldn't create a new instance for the "local" realm. In your react native app, you only want one instance, the synchronized one. That acts as your local database and it automatically synchronizes with the server. Write data to it and query it. Unless I am still misunderstanding your question..?

Comment: Ok, but how can I reference realm instance which is inside Realm.Sync.User.login closure? I would need to initialize this login in my root/top-level component and pass that instance to every component to access the data, realm.objects('Person').map... or is there is any other way to do this more efficiently? Thanks!

Comment: Yes. But I don't know why you need to encapsulate your realm instance in a component. You could just keep it somewhere as a variable or a module and pass that around